# Правильная реализация загрузки и замены файла на сервере

Tags: php, json, файлы, ftp, замена

Есть сервер который выполняет тяжелые запросы к стороннему API и через 15 минут примерно генерирует готовый файл в формате JSON, далее данный файл копируется по FTP на основной сервер заменяя предыдущий файл. Есть момент что в момент замены это файл может быть использован другими скриптами. Как правильнее и быстрее сделать подмену файла чтобы не возникло коллизии отсутствия или недоступности файла в момент замены. Язык выполнения всех операций PHP. Размер JSON файла может вырасти в дальнейшем и до 1 МБ и выше.

Comment: и сколько микросекунд копируется этот файл?

Comment: `flock` не подходит здесь?

Comment: Вполне можно использовать ссылочный механизм если это позволено системой - открывать файл по ссылке, копировать новый под другим именем, и замещать ссылку на него, после переименовывая в нужный. Хотя в любом случае если файл открыт в потоковом режиме то могут быть проблемы с чтением и смешиванием содержимого.